# Why I can't comment and disable this section of code into a JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, comments

I am working on some JSP pages and I don't know how correctly comment (to disable) a portion of code.

Into my code I have the following situation:

```
<!--
        <%if (tipoingresso.equalsIgnoreCase("NOLOGGED")) {%>
        <!--ATTENZIONE DIFFERENZA TRA FRONT END E SENZA FRONT END-->
        <!--<a href="/EdiWEA" target="_parent"><span class="linkboldblue10">&nbsp;&nbsp;Esci</span></a></ALIGN="LEFT">-->
        <!--<a href="../" target="_parent"><span class="linkboldblue10">&nbsp;&nbsp;Esci</span></a></ALIGN="LEFT">-->
            <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                   value="Esci" onclick="Javascript: loadingPopUp(); parent.document.location.href='../'"
                   onMouseOver="'Esco';return true"/>
        <%} else {%>
        <!--<a href="edi.do?serv=4.0"><img src="img/indietro.gif" width="64" height="20" border="0"></a></ALIGN="LEFT">-->
            <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                   value="Indietro" onclick="Javascript: loadingPopUp(); document.location.href = 'edi.do?serv=4.0'"
                   onMouseOver="'Indietro';return true"/>
        <%}%>
-->
```

As you can see I have an **if else** statment into my JSP and I want entirely comment and disable it.

The problem is that in this way can't work. I obtain that the selected input still shownin my page and also it is shown the **-->** comment close string after my button.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: It's `<%-- --%>` to ignore JSP code.

Comment: @Kayaman Tnx so much, if you post it I will accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How comment a JSP expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220243/how-comment-a-jsp-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<!-- -->` is ignored by the browser, `<%-- --%>` is ignored by the JSP engine.

Care must be taken, since when using `<!-- -->` the end result may look correct, but the JSP code is still executed (even if possible output isn't shown).

Comment: Tns so much also for this additional informations that I ignored :-)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for comment in JSP is

```
<%-- comment --%>
```