# How can I correctly comment the JSTL code into a JSP to correctly exclude it from execution?

Tags: jsp, jstl, comments

I am working on a JSP page.

I have noticed that if I want to exclude that this test is performed:

```
<!--<c:if test="${progetto.twp1009Tipostaprogetto.codTipSta==5}">-->
    SHOW SOME HTML ELEMENTS
<!--</c:if>-->
```

The use of the HTML comments  on the <c:if> tag don't works and the test still be performed.

Why? What am I missing? How can I correctly comment this JSTL test to exclude it and avoid that it is performed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How comment a JSP expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220243/how-comment-a-jsp-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the syntax for JSP comment:

```
<%-- Comment --%>

<%--<c:if test="${progetto.twp1009Tipostaprogetto.codTipSta==5}">--%>
    SHOW SOME HTML ELEMENTS
<%--</c:if>--%>
```